# How can I detect in Android that number which I'm calling (from code) is busy

Tags: android, telephony

how to detect from my Android class, that number which I call from code is busy and call is rejected ?
I try to use PhoneStateListener, but there is no state like 'busy'.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Most important info from [link](http://www.appbrain.com/app/auto-redial/com.adengappa): _Currently the Android SDK does not support detecting a busy signal._

Comment: Rest useful info: _The Redial application runs in the background listening to any call you dialed ending with '0' seconds ( All busy calls ends with 0 seconds in the call log. Some carriers do not support this). If the last call ended in 0 seconds then the application automatically redial the number. If your busy call does not end in 0 secs but ends with in certain time then you can configure "Consider a call busy field". If the busy call does not hang up at all then you need to manually hang up for the system to redial the last number immediately._

Comment: What about providers that play some message when the subscriber cannot be reached? What about call forwarding? Is this whole question an ad for this application "auto redial"?